# Debounce function not detecting when user reaches top of page because it is set to fire on the leading versus trailing edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a javascript function that changes the logo on scroll. I am using underscore.js's debounce function to prevent the scroll event from firing continuously while the user is scrolling the page. I have set a the debounce function to fire immediately (versus on the trailing edge of the scroll) so that the logo transitions without any lag time (current set wait time is 2 seconds). The issue is that if a user scrolls down the page and then scrolls back up to the top, the logo never transitions back because the debounce function fires before scrollTop can reach 0. Any suggestions to get the debounce function to fire in this case?

If I have the debounce function fire on the trailing edge of scroll, there is a lag time (2 seconds) before the logo loads. CSS transitions do not solve this issue because the logo is set as a background image. I am hoping there is a javascript solution rather than a css hack (crossfade hovers or something.) Do I need to write two separate functions? One for scrolling down and one for scrolling up?

```
function scrollHeader() {

            var top_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
            var logo = $('.site-title a')[0];
            var siteHeader = $('.site-header');
            if (top_offset == 0) {
                siteHeader.removeClass('scrolled');
                logo.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url( "logo.svg" ) !important');
            }
```

The else if conditional was added to prevent the logo from reloading on every scroll event (Chrome was causing a flickering issue otherwise)

```
 else if ( top_offset !== 0 && siteHeader.hasClass('scrolled')) {
                console.log ('header has scrolled class and is not at top');
            } else {
                siteHeader.addClass('scrolled');
                logo.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url( "logo.svg" ) !important');
            }
    }
```

Calling the debounce function (setting it to true fires the function immediately versus trailing edge):

```
    $(window).on('scroll', _.debounce(scrollHeader, 200, true));
```

Here is a link to the site if you want to see this issue in action:
http://205.134.254.129/~kosedigital/